# How can I avoid re-entrancy attack using PaymentSplitter.release

Tags: solidity

I've implemented the PaymentSplitter library into my ERC721 contract, When I run slither on the NFT contract. it's giving me the following warning :

***Reentrancy in PaymentSplitter.release(IERC20,address)***

Above is the function that is responsible for splitting the payment between the addresses:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

    contract Bear is ERC721, Ownable, PaymentSplitter, ReentrancyGuard{
    uint private teamLength;
    constructor(
            address[] memory _team,
            uint[] memory _teamShares,
            string memory _initBaseURI,
            string memory _notRevealedURI,
            bytes32 _merkleRoot) ERC721("Bear", "BR")
            PaymentSplitter(_team, _teamShares) {
            setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
            teamLength = _team.length;
            notRevealedURI = _notRevealedURI;
            merkleRoot = _merkleRoot;
        }
    
        modifier callerIsUser() {
            require(tx.origin == msg.sender, "Cannot be called by a contract");
            _;
        }
    
    
        function mint(address _account, uint256 _quantity, bytes32[] calldata _proof) external payable callerIsUser{
            uint price = PRICE;
            require(price != 0, "price connot be 0");
            //If this user on the whitelist ?
            require(isWhiteListed(msg.sender, _proof), "Not on the whitelist");
            // require((totalSupply() + _quantity) <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Beyond Max Supply");
            require(msg.value >= (PRICE * _quantity), "not enough funds ");
            _safeMint(_account, _quantity);
        }
    
        function releaseAll() external onlyOwner nonReentrant() {
                for(uint i = 0; i < teamLength; i++) {
                    release(payable(payee(i)));
                }
            }
    }
```

I'm missing something? Or there is a safe way to write this function to avoid vulnerabilities
Thank you

Comment: Could you share more code. Because I don't see any part here that would enable Re-entrancy. Even more so because you clay to use library, and those should be test.

Comment: I edited the post! What do you think?

Comment: Alright, I am looking at this, and as far as I can see, your code is legit (looks good). It says there is Re-entrancy in your openZeppelin library. And that makes no sense as they are audited. But I still went and took a look at their GitHub and I cant find no Re-entrancy. What version of openZeppelin are you using? It might be issue with some old libs?

Comment: What is even weirder, it gives you warning for function you aren't even using. (There are two release () functions inside the lib)

Comment: Where is the release function defined ? And by the way take care  a for loop could fail if the array is too big because of paid gas and gas limit

Comment: @Sky, I'm using openZeppelin library with a pragma solidity ^0.8.0. I don't understand why, but like you said these libraries are audited.

Comment: @MajdTL the array will have a maximum of 3 addresses, I don't think that would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The function `release(address payable account)` you're calling changes the state, then makes an external call to another contract `Address.sendValue(account, payment)`.

Malicious receiving contract can then call `release(...)` since it's public, that wouldn't have been a problem if you didn't have the loop that runs release again - after the state has changed.

Now this may not be a real weakness, but the compiler may not know that. Maybe it's possible to craft a smart receiver that calls `release` only on the 2nd time being called, hence bypassing the `nonReentrant()` protection.

Try removing the loop and see if the warning still shows.

Dangers of reentrancy explained at [SWC-107](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-107) (go there to see examples) -

> One of the major dangers of calling external contracts is that they can take over the control flow. In the reentrancy attack (a.k.a. recursive call attack), a malicious contract calls back into the calling contract before the first invocation of the function is finished. This may cause the different invocations of the function to interact in undesirable ways.
>
> The best practices to avoid Reentrancy weaknesses are:
>
> Make sure all internal state changes are performed before the call is executed. This is known as the Checks-Effects-Interactions pattern
> Use a reentrancy lock (ie. OpenZeppelin's ReentrancyGuard.

Comment: I am still not sure where Re-entrancy could happen in this code. What would be possible vector of attack here? Because I see no obvious exploit.

Comment: Explained above... the loop leads to state change **after** an external contract call, which is a big no-no. Exploits are not usually obvious, or they would be fixed. The point of SWC guidelines are to protect devs from making critical mistakes, even when they don't see an attack vector.